# Examples of locally compact group quotiented by compact subgroup, but not Riemannian symmetric space 

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

I would like to know examples of $G/K$ where $G$ is a locally compact group and $K$ is a compact subgroup of $G$.

I know about Riemannian symmetric spaces of Euclidean, compact and non-compact type. They can be realized as  $G/K$. I am wondering what are other prominent spaces (discrete and continuous) which can be written as $G/K$, where $G$ can be unimodular or non-unimodular. Perhaps homogeneous tree is an  example  outside the set of Riemannian symmetric spaces.

Comment: A homogeneous tree is not topologically homogeneous and thus can't be $G/K$. For $(G,K)=(SL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p),SL_2(\mathbf{Z}_p))$, indeed $G/K$ can be viewed as the vertex set of a tree.

Comment: Also note that $G/K$ is canonically a topological space with a transitive $G$-action. In many cases it carries a left-invariant distance but this is not canonical. So maybe you might specify a little what you have in mind.

Comment: What is with $K$ trivial? ;) The question should be more precise. Perhaps of interest two you, every connected locally compact group contains a normal subgroup such that the quotient is a Lie group.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments and sorry if you find the question not-so-precise.  Let me try again. I want examples of pair $(G, K)$ where $G$ is a locally compact group and $K$ a non trivial compact subgroup of $G$ such that $G/K$ is not a Riemannian symmetric space, i.e. $G/K$ is either not a symmetric space or it is not a Riemannian manifold, but for some reason the space $G/K$ is an important object. Robert Bryant has given an example.

Comment: @dhurup: you comment is still as ambiguous as the question. The statement "$G/K$ *is not* a symmetric space" is meaningless in two respects: 1/ *is* can mean "is isometric" or something weaker such as "is homomorphic to"; 2/ if you mean "is isometric to", it depends on the choice of a Riemannian metric.

Comment: Thanks @Yves. I will go for isometric to a symmetric space, because symmetric space is a geometric object, as given in Wikipedia:
``a symmetric space is a smooth manifold whose group of symmetries contains an inversion symmetry about every point.''    

Comment: @dhurup: OK but this depends on the choice of a Riemannian metric. In the other post, Robert Bryant gives examples of $G/K$ which are not symmetric for *any* choice of left-invariant-metric (because not homeomorphic to any symmetric space). But there are also cases where it is symmetric for some choice of left-invariant metric but not symmetric for some other choice. I think $(G,K)=(SO(3),1)$ is such an example.

Comment: Thanks very much Yves. I learnt a lot from you all. I am new here and will get back again. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of Riemannian homogeneous spaces that are not symmetric.  For example, consider the chain $\mathrm{SO}(2)\subset \mathrm{SO}(3)\subset \mathrm{SO}(4)$.  The quotient $\mathrm{SO}(4)/\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is not a symmetric space.

Comment: Actually in general if $G$ is a Lie group and $K$ is a compact subgroup, there are several $G$-invariant Riemannian metrics on $G/K$ and it might happen that some of them are symmetric. In your example I guess you mean that *none* is symmetric.

Comment: @Yves:  Actually, no, I didn't mean that.  That quotient actually turns out to be $S^2\times S^3$ topologically, so it actually can be written as a symmetric space, just not this way.  If you want an example that *can't* be written as a symmetric space, take $\mathrm{SU(3)}$ instead of $\mathrm{SO(4)}$ in the above sequence and consider $\mathrm{SU}(3)/\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

Comment: @Robert: I'm now confused: I understand from your comment that $SO(4)/SO(2)$ is homeomorphic to a symmetric space. But is it a symmetric space for some choice of $SO(4)$-invariant metric?

Comment: @Yves:  Well, there is a 4-parameter family of $\mathrm{SO}(4)$-invariant metrics on $\mathrm{SO}(4)/\mathrm{SO}(2)$, and one of them might be isometric to $S^3\times S^2 = \mathrm{SO}(4)/\mathrm{SO}(3)\times\mathrm{SO}(3)/\mathrm{SO}(2)$.  So maybe that was not the best example.  What I was trying to get at in my answer was that not all homogeneous spaces are symmetric spaces.  A better example is $\mathrm{SO}(5)/K$, where $K$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(5)$ that is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and that acts irreducibly on $\mathbb{R}^5$, as it's not homeomorphic to any symmetric space.